# Learn python the hard way, exercise 25

Tags: python, import

Hello everyone i am new to the python language and i have chosen learn python the hard way to learn it and to better my understanding... I am stumped on exercise 25 , When we import the code directly into the terminal

```
>>> import ex25
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
>>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
```

And then I get an attribute error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'break_words'
```

I am using python 2.7 on 
windows 7 please help..... http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html

Comment: And what do you have defined in `ex25.py` then?

Comment: `import ex25; dir(ex25)` will tell you which functions the module provides.

Comment: Probably a typo in ex25 or maybe you didn't copy/paste all of the source code from the webpage.

Comment: The link to the exercise gives all the information on the code what i have typed and defined. I followed Zeds instructions and his ran fine? I am going over the code again to check for typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that the exercise does not instruct the learner to save the file prior to the import. In order for this to work, you've got to save the code that defines the break_words function in a file called ex25.py using your text editor. Then, from the same directory open the python interpreter by typing:

```
python
```

and you should be able to import ex25 and run the break_words function which the ex25.py module has defined.

Comment: There seems to be a standing instruction throughout the book that the first block of code in each excercise will be saved to `ex??.py`. It seems likely the OP has already done this, or they would get an `ImportError` rather than an `AttributeError`.

Comment: I had to save it thank you very much David I never did save it -_- Facepalm ... Thank you all much for the help though..

Comment: @lvc I'm a fan of Shaw's work, but the notion of a meta-instruction for a hyperlinked book seems troubling without the meta instruction actually being referenced each time it's implied, else the casual reader who surfs in on that lesson in absentia of the prior lessons is lost. I'd suggest that imposing the additional stack space requirements on an already burdened learner is not good pedagogy.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your link for `ex25.py` does include that function - that yours doesn't suggests that you've somehow missed it when you transcribed the code into your file. Check that your `ex25.py` includes all the code from the page, and in particular contains this function (it's the very top one):

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
```

Consider *pasting* the code into your editor in preference to transcribing it in order to avoid errors like this.